# how to make a permanent redirect via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Google has indexed some URLs with empty value - space - at the end of each URL, I want to make a permanent redirect via `.htaccess` here is my code but it did not redirecting :

```
RewriteRule ^/profile/userx/([a-zA-Z])+/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]/'%20'$ https://mywebsite.net/profile/userx/([a-zA-Z]+)/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]/ [R=301,L]
```

How to say any URL with space at the end redirect it to that one without space?

Comment: Can you give an example of url with white space?

Comment: this is from my GSC https://mywebsite.net/profile/userx/fds/KJGgjhKJH/jhhJJFjhhJ/' '

Comment: Can you rather paste as text? It is unreadable for the space.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this rule as your topmost rule to remove 1+ whitespace from the end of URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\s+$ /$1 [L,NE,R=301]

# other rules go below this line
```

`\s+$` matches 1+ whitespace at the end of a URI and `.*` matches anything before whitespaces.